# Customer Community Plus Users unable to see "Delegated Tasks"

Tags: sharing, customer-community, activities

I have a Customer Community (Digital Experience) with a custom object. Customer users have a need to create Task (`Task`) records tied to this custom object and assign them to other customer users under the same Account. Because they're customer community users, I can't leverage a Role Hierarchy like I would be able to internally.

Under Organization Wide Default sharing, the custom object is set to "Private" and the Activity object is set to "Controlled by Parent". The intention being that the custom object can't be publicly available to all users, but if they can see the record they *should* be able to see the Activities tied to the object. This doesn't seem to be the case. If I create a Task as a community user, relate it to an object that both users can see (setting the `WhatId` on the Task record), and assign it (set the `OwnerId`) to the other user, then Task is created but the creator has no access to it and it doesn't show up under "Delegated Tasks" as I would expect.

Is there any way to make this specific configuration work with sharing? Anyone that sees the related record (`Task.WhatId`) should be able to see the Task record, regardless of who it is assigned to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the customer community users have edit FLS on the Public field in Activities?

Apparently this drives community wide access to tasks (must be able to edit and have the Public field checked):
[Error 'Insufficient Privileges' when Partner or Community Users access Tasks and Events](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000337277&type=1&mode=1&language=en_US)

You may need to update all affected Tasks and set the Public field to checked via dataloader / ETL of your choice.  There's also a knowledge article on setting up a workflow rule going forward for any new tasks: [Portal or community Users do not see Activity history on their Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000337701&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: Yes! Setting the Public (`IsVisibleInSelfService`) field to true fixed the issue. I've created a Task trigger to set that field to true going forward for Tasks created by community licensed users.